# Understanding a makefile recipe

Tags: makefile, kissfft

I'm working on an android project that involves native code and I'm trying to use the Kiss FFT library with the NDK. However, I'm having difficulty understanding the portion listed below of a makefile used by Kiss FFT. Can someone explain this to me?

I know that the first line defines the target `kiss_fft.s` and its prerequisites and that the next four lines are the recipe, of which line `3.` and `4.` are compiler commands. But I don't understand lines `2.` and `5.`

```
1. kiss_fft.s: kiss_fft.c kiss_fft.h _kiss_fft_guts.h
2.   [ -e kiss_fft.s ] && mv kiss_fft.s kiss_fft.s~ || true
3.   gcc -S kiss_fft.c -O3 -mtune=native -ffast-math -fomit-frame-pointer -unroll-loops -dA -fverbose-asm 
4.   gcc -o kiss_fft_short.s -S kiss_fft.c -O3 -mtune=native -ffast-math -fomit-frame-pointer -dA -fverbose-asm -DFIXED_POINT
5.   [ -e kiss_fft.s~ ] && diff kiss_fft.s~ kiss_fft.s || true
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The brackets represent a test; `man test` is the place to learn about the 'test' command. The && and || are 'and' and 'or' operators; it's a common script idiom to use them to execute one command followed conditionally by another. Line 2 appears to be 'test if the .s file exists, if so move it to a backup .s~ else continue ('true'). Line 5 is if the bkup .s~ exists, show a diff between it and the current .s else continue. The && do the 'if then' and the || is the else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Line `2.` moves the assembly code (kiss_fft.s) to a backup file if it exists, otherwise returns a true status, so the next line will execute.

Line `5.` shows you the differences between the previous assembler output from gcc and the current output, if there was previous output (moved into kiss_fft.s~ by step `2.`).

Comment: +1: And the `|| true` parts ensure that the overall command succeeds so that `make` does not stop processing if, for example, there is no file `kiss_fft.s` as line 2 is executed.